# JS convert to ASCII numbers and reverse

Tags: javascript, string

I stuck on this can you help in JavaScript [Alien message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocNHs.png)

Allowed languages
JavaScript

Your task is to translate a message in some alien language (let's call it Alienski).

The message could be created by following simple rules and from two known languages, English and Spanish.

Each word in Alienski is constructed by subtracting the letters from English and Spanish (absolute value) and that is the resulting letter.

There are two special cases. If in each of the words the symbol is '-' (hyphen) or ' ' (space) it is mandatory for it to be kept this way.

There won't be a case with a '-' (hyphen) and a ' ' (space) at the same time.

If one of the words is with more letters than the other just add the letters from the longer word to the result.
Example:
Copy

talk
hablar

Copy

a b c d....
0 1 2 3....

```
t - h = | 19 - 7 | = 12 = m
a - a = | 0 - 0 | = 0 = a
l - b = | 11 - 1 | = 10 = k
k - l = | 10 - 11 | = 1 = b
empty - a = a

empty - r = r

Result:
    makbar
```

---

I stuck from 3 hours on this. Here is my code so far

```
let englishWord = 'talk'
let spanishWord = 'hablar'
let engToDigit = [];
let spnToDigit = [];
let alien = [];

for (var i = 0; i < englishWord.length; i++) {
    engToDigit.push(englishWord.charCodeAt(i))
}
for (var y = 0; y < spanishWord.length; y++) {
    spnToDigit.push(spanishWord.charCodeAt(y))
}
let result = engToDigit.map((a, i) => a - spnToDigit[i]);

for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
    result[index] += 97;




console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should mention that this is an actual assignment. Furthermore, you should post your own attempts and specifically go into what problems you have, where they occure, and your own ideas and provide the code that you have attempted. Only THEN will people be able to help you. Stackoverflow is not a coding service, it's a community driven site made to help people, who stuck on a specific issue.

Comment: Screenshot of a written problem? You could have at least tried copy-paste.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here

Comment: Much better.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You also need to explicitly state how your output differs from your expected output.  Please read the links on the help page [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then finish editing your question.  At that point, your question will probably pass the internal review process to re-open your question.  You're almost there :).. Welcome to StackOverflow.  All the Best.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you need is to take this in small steps. First I would make a function that iterates through a string and converts each letter to its ASCII code. Try the following order:

1. Check if code is uppercase then get the numeric value.
2. Make sure charCode is greather than 96 and charCode is less than 123
3. Then turn all the codes to their numeric value by running and
   collecting in an array: charCode - 97
4. Else check if the code is lower case then get the numeric value.
5. Make sure that charCode is greater than 64 and charCode is less than 91.
6. Then turn all the codes to their numeric value by running and collecting in an array: charCode - 65
7. Else just add the value to the array.
8. Outside the above loop return an array that is joined.

When the array is joined it will be a string like "19,0,11,10,-,7,0,1,11,0,17".

9. Check if there is a space or a hyphen.
10. Then you can split the array on the result of step 9.
11. Then split each array on ",".
12. Loop through each array and subtract the values.
13. Convert the values back by adding 65 - because there is no way at this point to know if a character was upper case.
14. Then use String.fromCharCode(##) to convert the code back to the non-readable alien word.